# Ember: accessing sideloaded data in setupController with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using RESTAdapter and trying to figure out how to access sideloaded data.
A sample of the payload is:

```
{
    "category": {
        "categoryName": "test category",
        "id": 6,
        "products": [
            4419,
            502,
            3992
        ]
    },
    "products": [{
        "description": "Whatevs",
        "id": 4419,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": 114.95,
        "skuid": "S21046"
    }, {
        "description": "Whatevs",
        "id": 502,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "price": 114.95,
        "skuid": "SOLS2594"
    }, {
        "description": "Whatevs",
        "id": 3992,
        "name": "Product 3",
        "price": 114.95,
        "skuid": "S21015"
    }]
}
```

I can see 'category' and 'product' data models (and data) in the ember inspector, so I know they are being loaded.

I can even access the products in the template `model.products`.  BUT I can't access `model.products` in the route's `setupController`.  The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_relationships' of undefined
```

This is really perplexing me!  My route `model` hook is:

```
model(params) {
    return this.get('store').queryRecord('category', {
        id: params.id
    })
}
```

The `setupController` hook (that causes the error) is:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('results', model.products);
}
```

The 'category' model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    products: hasMany('product'),
    categoryName: attr('string')
});
```

The 'product' model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({

    name: attr('string'),
    skuid: attr('string'),
    price: attr('number'),
    description: attr('string')

});
```

My template (which works, if I remove the 'setupController' hook from the route):

```
{{#each model.products as |product|}}
{{product.name}} {{product.skuid}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

I'd like to be able to access `model.products` from the route's setupController so I can call it something else.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship returns Promises. so to get the result you need to use `then`. but  accessing it in template will work because template is by default promise aware.

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    //controller.set('results', model.products);
    model.get('products').then((result) => {
     controller.set('results',result);
    });
}
```

Please give read on [relationships as promises](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises) guide.